# How to send a soap method - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

I have an example from http request of soap:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS">
        <IN_USERNAME-VARCHAR2-IN>test</IN_USERNAME-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_SERVICEID-NUMBER-IN>2</IN_SERVICEID-NUMBER-IN>
        <IN_PASSWORD-VARCHAR2-IN>test123</IN_PASSWORD-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_9-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_9-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_8-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_8-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_7-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_7-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_6-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_6-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_5-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_5-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_4-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_4-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_3-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_3-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_2-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_2-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_10-VARCHAR2-IN>""</IN_PARAM_10-VARCHAR2-IN>
        <IN_PARAM_1-VARCHAR2-IN>111100002</IN_PARAM_1-VARCHAR2-IN>
    </SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

I wrote this  function and it doesn't return anything:

```
 public function sendP($params = array()  , $debug = false ){
 error_reporting(0);

$client = new SoapClient("http://smartcard.rmto.ir:9090/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS?wsdl");
$parameters['USERNAME']     = 'test' ;
$parameters['SERVICEID']    = 2;
$parameters['PASSWORD']     = 'test123';
$parameters['PARAM_1']      = '111100002';
//$parameters['text']         = iconv("UTF-8", 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT',$params['title']);

try{
  $status = $client->RETURN($parameters);}
  catch(SoapFault $e){
  1;
}

if($debug)
return $status;
```

}

```
sendP(array()):
```

where is my problem? I don't know `RETURN` function is correct or not.

Comment: http://smartcard.rmto.ir:9090/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS?wsdl

Comment: Could you find a solution for your question? I should implement this api for drivers using NodeJs. Please help me, if you solved it before.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in WSDL file, you must call the name of "xsd:element": SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput (it is a method you must call to send needed information). There is no "RETURN" method, you've mentioned in the code.

And also don't forget to copy exact names of parameters to send.
Try this example, I think it should work.

Good luck :)

```
public function sendP($params = array()  , $debug = false ){

$client = new SoapClient("http://smartcard.rmto.ir:9090/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS?wsdl");

$parameters['IN_USERNAME-VARCHAR2-IN'] = 'test' ;
$parameters['IN_SERVICEID-NUMBER-IN'] = 2;
$parameters['IN_PASSWORD-VARCHAR2-IN'] = 'test123';
$parameters['IN_PARAM_1-VARCHAR2-IN'] = '111100002';

try{
  $status = $client->SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput($parameters);}
  catch(SoapFault $e){
  1;
}

if($debug)
return $status;
```

Comment: I got this message: `Call to undefined function RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput()`

Comment: But we have send "SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput" not "RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput", please check the name of method you are calling from SOAP.

Comment: `$client` is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know your functions there is a really helpful function called `__getFunctions` - you will see an output like

```
0 => string 'RMTO_WEB_SERVICESOutput RMTO_WEB_SERVICES(SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput $parameters)' (length=87)
```

Basically you need to try to do something like that

```
try
    {
        $client = new SoapClient("http://smartcard.rmto.ir:9090/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS?wsdl", ['trace' => 1]);
        var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
        $parameters = [];
        //two alternatives here 
        $client->__soapCall('RMTO_WEB_SERVICES', $parameters);
        //or
        $client->RMTO_WEB_SERVICES($parameters);
    }
    catch (SoapFault $e)
    {
        echo '<h2>Exception Error</h2>';
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```